# Как перевести цифры в буквы

Tags: python

Заранее извиняюсь, только познаю основы программирования)

К примеру мне написали цифры, которые соответствуют номеру в русском алфавите, и мне нужно сделать предложение единым. Как сделать команду, которая из моего словаря выберет конкретно нужные мне цифры и я смогу через принт вывести само предложение, ниже написал список букв относительно цифр

```
numwords = {1: 'А', 2: 'Б', 3: 'В', 4: 'Г', 5: 'Д',
            6: 'Е', 7: 'Ё', 8: 'Ж', 9: 'З', 10: 'И',
            11: 'Й', 12: 'К', 13: 'Л', 14: 'М',
            15: 'Н', 16: 'О', 17: 'П', 18: 'Р', 19: 'С',
            20: 'Т', 21: 'У', 22: 'Ф', 23: 'Х', 
            24: 'Ц', 25: 'Ч', 26: 'Ш',
            27: 'Щ', 28: 'Ъ', 29: 'Ы', 30: 'Ь',
            31: 'Э', 32: 'Ю', 33: 'Я'}
```

Comment: Цифра это "1". А 1 это число. У вас - числа.

Answer (score 4):

Хочешь познать программирование - всегда пытайся, попытки прикрепляй, тогда будем разбираться, а так ты просто обозначил задачу

```
numwords = {num: letter for num, letter in
                enumerate(" абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя")}


def decryptor(crypted_message):
    message = ""
    for i in crypted_message:
        message += numwords[int(i)]
    return message


print(decryptor([17, 18, 10, 3, 6, 20, 0, 14, 10, 18]))
```

> привет мир

Из советов по данному вопросу: почитай про абстракции списков/словарей, про функции enumerate и zip.

Comment: `''.join(map(numwords.__getitem__, crypted_message))`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, не думаю, что начинающему будет понятна такая структура. Но решение элегантное, плюсую